# Copy directories and their contents async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, file-io

I have found [this solution on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx) that can copy files from a one directory to another, but it only copies from the main directory  and not the sub-directories.

How can I modify this solution so it will also copy all of the folders and their contents?

```
string StartDirectory = @"C:\Users\...";
string EndDirectory = @"C:\Users\....";

 //Creates all of the directories and sub-directories
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(StartDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(StartDirectory, EndDirectory));

foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(StartDirectory))
{
       using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
       {
             using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(EndDirectory + filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
             {
                  await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
              }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it with two loops, one for all of the sub-directories (the first) and one for the main directory:

```
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(StartDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(StartDirectory, EndDirectory));
                foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath))
                {
                    using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(filename.Replace(StartDirectory, EndDirectory)))
                        {

                            await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(StartDirectory))
            {
                using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(EndDirectory + filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
                    {

                        await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

Expand the first loop to enclose the inner loop and it should work.  You are searching all folders with the first for loop but only enumerating the files in the top level folder.  You need to enumerate the files in each of the sub-folders as well.  Also, DirectoryInfo will be easier to work with than Directory in this case.

```
DirectoryInfo StartDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\...");
DirectoryInfo EndDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\....");

//Creates all of the directories and sub-directories
foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in StartDirectory.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string dirPath = dirInfo.FullName;
    string outputPath = dirPath.Replace(StartDirectory.FullName, EndDirectory.FullName);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);

    foreach (FileInfo file in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        using (FileStream SourceStream = file.OpenRead())
        {
            using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(outputPath + file.Name))
            {
                SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlonMln - updated to something that should work better for you now.  I had forgotten about the static File and Directory stuff.  FileInfo and DirectoryInfo give far more control and are more object oriented, so I always use them.  As you can see, it makes the syntax a little different.  This could still be done a little bit cleaner, but it should serve your purposes I think.